# Test a void method that instantiates multiple classes

Tags: java, unit-testing

Can anyone help me test this method:

```
public void initialize() {
    Person person = new Person();
    person.becomeActive();
    Client client = new Client();
    client.setClient(person);
    Manager manager = new Manager();
}
```

I have tried using a `Mockito` spy but I don't know how to test it.
I have also read about the`factory pattern` which would be an elegant solution, but I am looking for something that will not change the initial method if it's possible.

Any ideas on how I can test `initialize` method?

Comment: Without changing the method, the only test would be whether or not the method throws an exception.  The method itself has no observable side-effects to be validated.  It doesn't actually *do* anything.  (And, as such, is essentially superfluous and can probably just be removed entirely.)

Comment: What does this initialize method do? You are not "saving" your variables into some class members. For Testing you would call your initialize and then you could assert notNull for these class variables.

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided, there isn't a way to unit-test the `initialize()` method.

**Why?**
You are creating 3 variables that will not live outside the scope of the method.  So there isn't any observable output, unless the creation of these objects effects some static state of the program (which was not mentioned in the OP as of writing this answer).

**Instead:**
Write unit tests for the constructors of the `Person`, `Client`, and `Manager` classes and the `Person.becomeActive()` and `Client.setClient(Person)` methods.